# Why does pinging of 200 bytes take long than pinging of 5000 bytes?

Tags: linux, networking, ping

So I have 5 machines connected in a LAN, each running Ubuntu 14 and have assigned a unique static IP. I am trying to calculate an estimate of the time it takes for a group of bytes to be transmitted and received to one of these machines. Here are some ping results I got by averaging 20 iterations of the ping each:

```
ping -s [size] -c 20 [IP address]
```

- 200 bytes - roughly 0.6ms
- 2,500 bytes - roughly 0.4ms
- 10,000 bytes - roughly 0.4ms

How is it possible for a smaller packet size of 200 bytes take longer than 2500 or 10000 bytes?

*Please note that they were tested all on the same machine, to the same address.*

Comment: While it doesn't answer your question, a better, more scaleable performance metric might be sending a larger blocks using whichever application or protocol that will be used for production.

Comment: You should write how you get this results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ping` reported a similar result for me to `localhost`:

```
...
208 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=99 ttl=64 time=0.163 ms

--- localhost ping statistics ---
100 packets transmitted, 100 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.078/0.172/0.269/0.044 ms
```

```
2008 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=99 ttl=64 time=0.188 ms

--- localhost ping statistics ---
100 packets transmitted, 100 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.065/0.170/0.262/0.042 ms
```

However, `ping` isn't particularly precise with respect to reporting round-trip times, say, compared to `tcpdump`:

`ping` reports a RTT of 0.076 ms for a 208 byte packet, while `tcpdump` shows the packet leaving and returning in just 0.033 ms:

```
tcpdump -i lo0 -nK -t 5 -c 2 icmp

 00:00:00.000000 IP 127.0.0.1 > 127.0.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 37477, seq 0, length 208
 00:00:00.000033 IP 127.0.0.1 > 127.0.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 37477, seq 0, length 208
```

For a 2008 byte packet, `ping` reported a RTT of 0.087 ms, though `tcpdump` reported just 0.042 ms.

In short, `ping` is a program that has overhead, and system dependencies that make it unsuitable for measuring tiny differences:  it's not a precision tool.